# Filter options of one SELECT control according to another SELECT control options with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two select controls . the first one contains names of countries and the another one contains cities names . I need to make the second one display names of the cities of selected country from the first one.

Comment: If this is homework, you should tag it as such

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify how you wanted to accomplish it (postback vs. ajax), so, I picked `postback`.

1. Create a [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) control for countries (in my example it's **ddlCountries**)
2. Bind the list of countries to it - probably in `Page_Load` wrapped in an `if (!Page.IsPostback)`
3. Double-click on the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to create a handler for that event.

Then handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event on the `DropDownList` control for country and set the `DropDownList` for cities (*untested example*):

```
Protected void ddlCountries_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the list of cities for the selected country 
    // using ddlCountries.SelectedItem.Value;
    ddlCities.DataSource = GetCities(ddlCountries.SelectedItem.Value);
    ddlCities.DataTextField="CityName";
    ddlCities.DataValueField="CityName";
    ddlCities.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to mention that! :(
but you picked the right one .
thank you, it worked .

Comment: If this answer truly worked for you, you may want to consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be on country selection:

```
var citiesToDisplay = Cities.Where(city=> city.CountryId == selectedCountryId);
```